# Bin packing problem using bit masking

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming, c++

We have **n box** and an **array of weights**, where weight of ith box is given by arr[i]. We have a container which can carry a maximum weight of **w**. Now we have to find **minimum** number of containers required to pack these N items.

> Exact question link : -
> [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/coding-round-practice/challenges/michaels-worries)
>
> Useful Resources :-
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bin-packing-problem-minimize-number-of-used-bins/

If the constraints are small, we can solve this problem using Dynamic programming with bitmasking. Here is a code which i wrote to implement the same. However it is giving Time limit exceeded.

**Constraints:**

1 <= n <= 20

1 <= w <= 10^9

0 <= arr[i] <= w

**Pseudo code**

> A set bit in bitmask states that it is available for placing in
> containers and vice versa.
>
> Step 1: find the total weight of all boxes represented by all bitmask and
> store it in a sums array.
>
> Step 2: Initialize the dp for 1 container, it can be simply done by checking the weight limit of one container
>
> Step 3: Create a 2d boolean array, dp, where dp[i][j] states that for
> given bitmask "j", will "i" container be enough to place all boxes.
> Thus dp[i][j] = true or false
>
> Step 4: Iterate for number of containers from 2 to size of(box
> array)(since the size of box array can always be the answer)
>
> Now run an inner loop for every bitmask( to check if this bitmask is
> possible with i containers.)
>
> Now run another inner loop for every bitmask to enumerate its submask
> and check the various transition states associated with it i.e. if any
> submask is given to a new container, can the remaining i-1 containers
> can be used to place boxes represented by (bitmask - submask)

Comment: What is the **algorithm** you used? please do not put full  code (but rather, put pseudocode), as coding questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: I have tried to used dynamic programming with bitmasking to solve this. The basic question which we want to answer for any given number of available boxes is what is the minimum number of containers required to put all these boxes. If we are given that for certain bitmask of boxes (for ex - 1010 , box 1 and box 3 available), if they can be placed in i containers then => dp[i][bitmask] = true. This information can be used to solve the states with submasks of given bitmask as well.

Comment: Please write that in the body of the question then, instead of the full code.

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question so it reads well for someone who sees it and addresses the feedback.  Please replace the code with a concise description of the algorithm: e.g., pseudocode or mathematics.  Code is off-topic here.  What's the asymptotic running time of the best algorithm you have?